# Issue with rotation on negative

Tags: unity-game-engine

GameObject faces correctly when in positive transform but as soon as it hits negative it flips and faces the wrong way.

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (currentWaypoint), 
            rotationspeed * Time.smoothDeltaTime);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,currentWaypoint,speed * Time.deltaTime);
        Debug.Log (currentWaypoint);
```

It begins to flip as logs below:

> (1.5, 0.0, 0.0) UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/Enemy.cs:71)
>
> (-0.5, 0.0, -1.0) UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
>   c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/Enemy.cs:71)

I'm hoping someone will be able to point me in the right direction with this

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the character using the Vector3 property with the rotate function,
Set a variable for speed control,then an input function to control your rotation as follows.,

```
private float speed = 20;

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.M))
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * speed* Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.B))
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * speed* Time.deltaTime);
    }
```